# How to make many characteres to be just one in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have the following sentence:

```
sentence_1 = "online auto body"
```

And I have added at the beginning and at the end of it the following character `<s>` indicating the start and the end of it, therefore my sentence is now as follows:

```
sentence = "<s> online auto body <s>"
```

I would like to make trigrams of the words in `sentence_1` as follows:

```
('<s>','o','n')
('o', 'n', 'l')
('n', 'l', 'i')
('l', 'i', 'n')
('i', 'n', 'e')
('a', 'u', 't')
('u', 't', 'o')
('b', 'o', 'd')
('o', 'd', 'y')
('d', 'y', '<s>)
```

What I tried to do so is the following piece of code:

```
from nltk import ngrams
n = 3
word_3grams = ngrams(sentence.split(), n)


for w_grams in word_3grams:
    w_gram = list(w_grams)
    print(w_grams[0])
    for i in range(0,n):
        letter_3grams = ngrams(w_grams[i],3)
        for l_gram in letter_3grams:
            print(l_gram)
```

But what I get is:

```
('<', 's', '>')
('o', 'n', 'l')
('n', 'l', 'i')
('l', 'i', 'n')
('i', 'n', 'e')
('a', 'u', 't')
('u', 't', 'o')
```

And so on.

The question is how could I avoid the splitting in 3-grams of `<s>` and take it as a whole?

Comment: Turn your strings into lists. Add `<s>` in the first and last list. Apply your existing trigram algorithm.

Comment: `<s>` is not a character, but a 3 char string. Why do you not remove `<s>` from the string that you pass to `ngrams` and add a tuple afterwards manually to the list.

Comment: Use **one** char that you know it won't appear in your text (e.g. `\xFF`). And while you're designing a sort of  *XML* like protocol, you'd better do it right: have separate markers for begin and end, so when you encounter one to know whether the string is beginning or ending (e.g. `"\xFE online auto body \xFF"`). Also is ignoring the *SPACE*s intended?

Comment: @CristiFati, the instructions I am following told me to it like so but sure the way you said makes more sense. And yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired output shows that spaces are removed in your input string, so don't forget to replace spaces by an empty string before splitting:

```
sentence_1 = "online auto body"

lst = ['<s>'] + list(sentence_1.replace(' ','')) + ['<s>']
tri = [tuple(lst[n:n+3]) for n in range(len(lst)-2)]
print(tri)
```

This code creates a list of trigrams, that you may process further:

```
[('<s>', 'o', 'n'), ('o', 'n', 'l'), ('n', 'l', 'i'), ('l', 'i', 'n'), ('i', 'n', 'e'), ('n', 'e', 'a'), ('e', 'a', 'u'), ('a', 'u', 't'), ('u', 't', 'o'), ('t', 'o', 'b'), ('o', 'b', 'o'), ('b', 'o', 'd'), ('o', 'd', 'y'), ('d', 'y', '<s>')]
```

If you only want to print the trigrams, replace the last two lines by:

```
print('\n'.join(str(tuple(lst[n:n+3])) for n in range(len(lst)-2)))
```

Output:

```
('<s>', 'o', 'n')
('o', 'n', 'l')
('n', 'l', 'i')
('l', 'i', 'n')
('i', 'n', 'e')
('n', 'e', 'a')
('e', 'a', 'u')
('a', 'u', 't')
('u', 't', 'o')
('t', 'o', 'b')
('o', 'b', 'o')
('b', 'o', 'd')
('o', 'd', 'y')
('d', 'y', '<s>')
```

Comment: @pylang: No it does not work (see my comment on your answer)

Comment: You are right.  You can split the string into iterables and rejoin it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the third-party [`more_itertools.stagger`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.stagger) tool (install via `> pip install more_itertools`):

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


sentence_1 = "online auto body" 
s = "".join(sentence_1)

list(mit.stagger(s, fillvalue="<s>", longest=True))[:-1]
```

Output

```
[('<s>', 'o', 'n'),
 ('o', 'n', 'l'),
 ('n', 'l', 'i'),
 ('l', 'i', 'n'),
 ('i', 'n', 'e'),
 ('n', 'e', 'a'),
 ('e', 'a', 'u'),
 ('a', 'u', 't'),
 ('u', 't', 'o'),
 ('t', 'o', 'b'),
 ('o', 'b', 'o'),
 ('b', 'o', 'd'),
 ('o', 'd', 'y'),
 ('d', 'y', '<s>')]
```

This tool yields tuples with items offset from the input iterable.  The trailing offsets are replaced by the `fillvalue` parameter.

Comment: `"".join("foo bar")` returns `'foo bar'` so spaces are not removed. You have to use `"".join("foo bar".split())`